# Enforce key size on virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

This is the layout I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/h0oa3Lps/  All keys are the same size.

In my application I have this code. The js is at the bottom of my jade file:

```
    $('.keyboard')
        .keyboard({
            layout: 'custom',
            customLayout: {
                'default' : [
                    '1 2 3 {c}',
                    '4 5 6 {b}',
                    '7 8 9 {dec}',
                    '{left} {right} 0 {a}'
                ]
            },
            maxLength : 6,
            restrictInput : true,
            useCombos : false,
            acceptValid : true,
            validate : function(keyboard, value, isClosing){
                // only make valid if input is between 0 and 100 inclusive
                return value >= 0.0 && value <= 100.0;
            }
        })
        .addTyping();
```

When using css/keyboard.min.css, the left arrow, right arrow and backspace keys are slightly larger than the other keys. Also the text positioning is off. Image:
[image: keyboard-min-css]

If I switch to css/keyboard-basic.min.css the arrow keys are the same size as regular keys but the esc, backspace, and accept keys are twice the size as the regular keys.  Also this takes up half of the screen (since it's not using the jquery-ui positioning). Image:

[image: keyboard-basic-min-css]

How do I enforce uniform key size?

If it makes any difference I am using Node, Express and Foundation v5.5.3 plus I have just updated to the latest versions of jQuery, jQuery-ui and jQuery.keyboard.

Comment: When I test your code in the fiddle, it works as expected. I wonder if this is a CSS issue. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0zc4wh61/

Comment: Also updated to jQuery 3.2.1 and UI 1.12.1 just to ensure it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0zc4wh61/2/

Comment: I suspect it might be down to media selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I copied the unminified css of `keyboard.css` to a `keyboard-butchered.css`. I then started experimenting with the styles in `keyboard-basic.css` and eventually came up with the following that partially answered my question:

```
.ui-keyboard {
    /* adjust overall keyboard size using "font-size" */
    font-size: 28px; /* increase button size for small screen */
    text-align: center;
    background: #fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px;

    /* include the following setting to place the
    keyboard at the bottom of the browser window */
    left: 0px;
    top: auto;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* see issue #484 */
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation; 
}
```

I then mixed in the style for the keyboard button. This gives the correct style as seen in the jsfiddle demo (but jumbo sized).

```
.ui-keyboard-button {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    margin: 1px;
    min-width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: white;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, white 0%, #e3e3e3 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(-90deg, white 0%, #e3e3e3 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore;
}
```